# How can I add sms auto verification in flutter app using firebase_auth (Phone Authentication)?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

In my flutter app I am using *firebase* phone authentication for login purpose. in all way, its working perfectly. By using my current code I have to add *sms* code explicitly when I receive the code.

How can I make this sms verification automatically in my flutter app?

```dart
    Future<void> _sendCodeToPhoneNumber() async {

    final String phone = country + phoneNumberController.text;

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential credential) {
      setState(() {
        print(
            'Inside _sendCodeToPhoneNumber: signInWithPhoneNumber auto succeeded: $credential');
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
      setState(() {
        print(
            'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}');
      });
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      this._verificationId = verificationId;
      print("code sent to " + phone);
      setState(() {
        this.status = AuthStatus.SMS_AUTH;
      });
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      this._verificationId = verificationId;

      print("time out");
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phone,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In onPhoneVerificationCompleted Write this:

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted phoneVerificationCompleted =
    (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
  print('Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential');
  await _auth
      .signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
      .then((AuthResult result) {
    // signin is successful
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = result.user;
    // check if user exists already
    getUserDetailsById(firebaseUser.uid).then((value) async {
      if (value == null) {
        // new user sign in
        addDataToFirestore(firebaseUser).then((value) => {
              // new user data added to db
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Home(),
              ),
            );
          });
      } else {
        // user already signed in
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Home(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you answer correctly, do you want to auto-verify the SMS code?

That's possible only in Android (the function verificationCompleted returns an object credentials when the auto-verification process occurs) but you should always have a fallback with the UI to verify the SMS code, as is not always possible for Android to auto verify the SMS code.

Also, you need the code to generate the credentials and then do the sign-in/sign-up process.

Let me know if this answered your question.

Comment: Is it impossible to auti-fill android and ios using flutter?

Comment: So Android has the ability to skip the entire otp verification process, it handles it in the verificationCompleted method, as you can see it returns an object of type AuthCredentials which are used to login the user. iOS has not this possibility according to the docs , it must pass through OTP verification. If you are referring about the autocomplete function of the textfield it is not linked to this plugin but yu can try to search how to use it with flutter

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use this google sms receiver API. I think this one can be used for auto fill sms code https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview